# AES256 on Python: Multi-pass error?

Tags: python, encryption, encoding, utf-8, aes

I'm having trouble doing multi-pass encryption using AES256 encryption in Python.

Here are my functions that I've worked on so far:

**Encryption:**

```
def AESEncrypt(plaintext, password, passes = 1):
    try:
        salt = Random.get_random_bytes(32)
        iv = Random.get_random_bytes(16)

        hmacsha256 = get_prf("hmac-sha256")
        key = KDF.PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, 4096, hmacsha256[0])

        aesManaged = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)

        padlength = 0
        padByte = chr(0)
        if len(plaintext) < 16:
            padlength = 16 - len(plaintext)
            padByte = chr(padlength)
        else:
            padlength = 16 - (len(plaintext) % 16)
            padByte = chr(padlength)    
            for i in range(padlength):
                plaintext = plaintext + b"\x00"
        countByte = chr(passes)
        if passes == 1:
            ciphertext = countByte + padByte + iv + salt + aesManaged.encrypt(plaintext)
    elif passes >= 2:
        ciphertext = aesManaged.encrypt(plaintext)
            for i in range(passes - 1):
                ciphertext = aesManaged.encrypt(ciphertext)
                ciphertext = countByte + padByte + iv + salt + ciphertext
    return ciphertext
except:
    print str(sys.exc_info()[1])
    return None
```

**Decryption:**

```
def AESDecrypt(ciphertext, password):
    try:
        base_cipher = ciphertext

        passes = ord(base_cipher[0])
        padLength = ord(base_cipher[1])
        iv = base_cipher[2:18]
        salt = base_cipher[18:50]
        hmacsha256 = get_prf("hmac-sha256")
        key = KDF.PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, 4096, hmacsha256[0])
        aesManaged = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)

        msg_cipher = base_cipher[50:]

        if passes == 1:
            plaintext_bytes = aesManaged.decrypt(msg_cipher)
        elif passes >= 2:
            plaintext_bytes = aesManaged.decrypt(msg_cipher)
            for i in range(passes - 1):
                plaintext_bytes = aesManaged.decrypt(plaintext_bytes)

        if padLength > 0:
            ptLength = len(plaintext_bytes)
            plaintext_bytes = plaintext_bytes[:ptLength - padLength]
        return plaintext_bytes
    except:
        print str(sys.exc_info()[1])
        return None
```

As far as writing binary data, it's working fine with single-pass and multi-pass encryption. When it comes to encrypting text data (like text files or messages), it starts to bug out when I use a `passes` value more than 1 when decrypting.

For example, if I just use plain text like `"Hello World!"` with the above procedures or with UTF-16, the multi-pass encryption will give me a bunch of corrupt text (that garbles at most half the message) with the remaining message correctly decrypted.

When I use UTF-8 encoding like `"Hello World".encode('utf-8')` also with the same procedure, I get an error that says (although the byte number and position changes every time I run it):

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xf7 in position 0: invalid start byte

Is it something I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

After looking at the Python docs for `bytes` and `bytearray` types, I tried converting the portions that should be considered a byte array:

(I plan on doing the decryption and the type detection portions once I get the encryption right)

```
def AESEncrypt(plaintext, password, passes = 1):
    try:
        plaintext = bytearray(plaintext)
        salt = bytes(Random.get_random_bytes(32))
        iv = bytes(Random.get_random_bytes(16))

        hmacsha256 = get_prf("hmac-sha256")
        key = KDF.PBKDF2(password, salt, 32, 4096, hmacsha256[0])

        aesManaged = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC,iv)

        padlength = 0
        padByte = chr(0)
        if len(plaintext) < 16:
            padlength = 16 - len(plaintext)
            padByte = chr(padlength)
        else:
            padlength = 16 - (len(plaintext) % 16)
            padByte = chr(padlength)    
            for i in range(padlength):
                plaintext.append(b"\x00")
        countByte = chr(passes)
        if passes == 1:
            ciphertext = bytes(countByte + padByte + iv + salt + aesManaged.encrypt(plaintext))
        elif passes >= 2:
            ciphertext = bytearray(aesManaged.encrypt(plaintext))
        for i in range(passes - 1):
            ciphertext = aesManaged.encrypt(ciphertext)
        ciphertext.insert(0, salt)
        ciphertext.insert(0, iv)
        ciphertext.insert(0, padByte)
        ciphertext.insert(0, countByte)
        return ciphertext
    except:
        print "Error on line %d: %s" % (sys.exc_traceback.tb_lineno, str(sys.exc_info()[1]))
        return None
```

Now I'm just getting `argument must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray` errors on parts that should be byte arrays but are asking for strings. With this current example, it's on the line after `elif passes >=2` where it was converting the ciphertext to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues:

1. `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `utf-8` instead of `ascii` in your Python 2 environment. It may break some Python libraries on some input silently. It is a way to create hard to debug data-dependant bugs. Look for `sys.setdefaultencoding` in `site`, `sitecustomize`, `usercustomize` modules
2. `bytestring.encode('utf-8')` is equivalent to `bytestring.decode(sys.getdefaultencoding()).encode('utf-8')`. Don't call `.encode(char_encoding)` on a bytestring, use it on Unicode strings instead.

Don't mix bytes and Unicode strings. For simplicity, start with API that works only with bytes i.e., reject Unicode strings and make sure your code doesn't return them by accident (it is appropriate for encrypt/decrypt methods).

---

`bytearray()` is a mutable sequence of bytes. You can use it almost everywhere where `bytes` (immutable sequence of bytes) or (more generally) any object that supports [buffer interface](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/buffer.html#bufferobjects) can be used.

It seems `aesManaged.encrypt(plaintext)` raises an exception when `plaintext` is a bytearray. Your code doesn't modify `plaintext` inplace except for the `.append` call that you could replace with `.rjust`-based code. Until `AES` modules is updated to support `bytearray`; don't use `bytearray` in this case or convert it (try `buffer(plaintext)`) before you pass it to `AES` methods that do not support `bytearray` directly.

There are unnecessary type conversions in your code. Remove them.

Comment: When you said "works only with bytes", that's what exactly I had in mind - I want my functions to be able to encrypt/decrypt bytes. But how would I convert a Unicode string to a byte array?

Comment: @ki2ne: `bytestring = unicode_string.encode(character_encoding)`

Comment: After looking up the Python documentation, could I use the `bytearray` type (and converting the strings using `bytearray()`)to avoid confusing and/or mixing up strings and byte arrays?

Comment: @ki2ne: `bytearray()` is just a mutable sequence of bytes. You can use it almost everywhere where `bytes` (immutable sequence of bytes) can be used.

Comment: I'm working with the bytearray type now (convert it to bytearray on the first pass), but now the AES object is saying I can't use the bytearray for the 2nd pass: `argument must be string or read-only buffer, not bytearray`.

Comment: Provide a [complete minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the issue and the full traceback. Don't put it in the comments, [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22398574/edit) or ask a new one.

Comment: @ki2ne: I've updated the answer to explain the `bytearray` error.